# Get list of youtube songs

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to get list of best songs based on genre.
For example if i send request with keyword "pop" the it should return me list of music from that genre sorted by popularity (views). 
And next question would be can i use that list as playlist for radio, I mean would it be playable audio or i will just get list of songs as string?

I try to generate code, but I don´t know all details for request:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.channels.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
      "part": "snippet",
      "categoryId": "music",
      "maxResults": 25
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

and because of that i get error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.channel",
    "reason": "categoryNotFound",
    "message": "Channel category not found.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "categoryId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Channel category not found."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"categoryId": "music"` - doesn't look valid for me.

Please search what's the category for "music" - in the request [videoCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?hl=en&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22US%22%7D), in region `US`, the `videoCategoryId` is `10`.

My suggestion is:

Change this value:

```
"categoryId": "music",
```

To:

```
"categoryId": "10", -- Changed value
```